# Talend-Convert IF-THEN ELSE into Ternary operator

Tags: java, if-statement, tableau-api, talend

We are trying to turn IF-THEN-ELSE statement of tableau Reporting/BI tool  **INTO** TERNARY OPERATOR Java Based Talend tool Or JAVA based IF-THEN-ELSE

**Input Data**

```
if isnull([Ship Date (Calculated)]) then
(if (attr(trim([Corp Acct Name])) = 'ABC' 
or attr(trim([Corp Acct Name])) ='BCD' 
or attr(trim([Corp Acct Name])) ='CDE') 
then 
(if DATEPART('weekday',ATTR([ ShipDate])) =1 then (attr([ ShipDate])-3)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',ATTR([ ShipDate])) =2 then (attr([ ShipDate])-3)
else  (attr([ShipDate])-2) END
) else (if DATEPART('weekday',ATTR([ ShipDate])) =1 then (attr([ ShipDate])-2)
else  (attr([ ShipDate])-1) END
) end)
ELSE
(if (attr(trim([Corp Acct Name])) = 'ABC' 
or attr(trim([Corp Acct Name])) ='BCD' 
or attr(trim([Corp Acct Name])) ='CDE') 
then 
(if DATEPART('weekday',[Ship Date (Calculated)])=1 then ([Ship Date (Calculated)]-3)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',[Ship Date (Calculated)])=2 then ([Ship Date (Calculated)]-3)
else ([Ship Date (Calculated)]-2) end)
 else (if DATEPART('weekday',[Ship Date (Calculated)])=1 then ([Ship Date (Calculated)]-2)
else ([Ship Date (Calculated)]-1) end) end)
END
```

**Used Field and its data type here**

```
[Ship Date (Calculated)]- date
[Corp Acct Name] -String
[ ShipDate] - Date
```

**We tried:**

```
row1.ShipDateCalculated==null?("ABC".equalsIgnoreCase(row1.CorpAcctName) || "BCD".equalsIgnoreCase(row1.CorpAcctName
||"CDE".equalsIgnoreCase(row1.CorpAcctName))?(TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.ShipDate) ==1?TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-3,"dd"):
(TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.ShipDate) ==2?TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-3,"dd"):TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-2,"dd")
:(TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.ShipDate) ==1?TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-2,"dd"):TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-1,"dd"):""))
```

**Output Data:**

Looking for ternary Operator based on JAVA.

```
condition1?(condition2?value if true:value if false): (condition3?value if true:value if false)
```

More Error : After adding else part on  current  tmap syntax.Getting error

[image]

Comment: You should convert the code to Java and put it into a tJavaRow component to process the data. Alternatively, you could re-create all the code you created with Talend components and Talend checks. This could become a little cleaner but has a few more components in the end.

Comment: I am trying to capture into  tmap  ternery Operator expression

Comment: Please show us what you have tried for now and we could start from here to make it work.

Comment: @Corentin  Update  Tried section  within Question. Please have a look on it.

Answer (score 2):

Parenthesis are all messed up in your code, it is not compiling.
You must go in to the "Code" tab , close to the Designer tab in your job, to get the detail of your code. It will show you the compiling errors, and give more details than the error popup.

```
    row1.ShipDateCalculated==null?
("ABC".equalsIgnoreCase(row1.CorpAcctName) || "BCD".equalsIgnoreCase(row1.CorpAcctName)||"CDE".equalsIgnoreCase(row1.CorpAcctName))?
TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.ShipDate) ==1?
TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-3,"dd"):
TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.ShipDate) ==2?
TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-3,"dd"):
TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-2,"dd"):
TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.ShipDate) ==1?
TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-2,"dd"):
TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yyyy", row1.ShipDate ),"MM/dd/yyyy",-1,"dd"):
""
```

Comment: When I am running the same expression throwing this error http://paste.ofcode.org/TEBUEXqdAT6iVcqnMkpuW5. else it looks fine.

Comment: Issue is resolved now. missing is one ")". ShipDateCalculated IS not resolved as a field. it is output column. So  i  am trying to use output column during transformation of  this output column. Is there any way in talend ?

Comment: I just tested  above synatax into talend  testing server. it is  throwing this stack trace.http://paste.ofcode.org/nGSfyVb7NLJHuZRUk6rW5y

Comment: "   The method equalsIgnoreCase(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (Date)" => this message is pretty clear, just check the type of your field CorpAcctName...

Comment: Thanks I checked and resolved it. http://pastie.org/10951640 after using  above Expression . Getting   following error
http://paste.ofcode.org/avQhF4gHPGtdVnZdvDPiVh

Comment: Can we  talk on Chat  ?

Comment: When i  am  try to  run  above expression it is not calculating   date value. all date values are coming blank.

Comment: Here is exact code by line : when i am using java debug.please find  Attachement  in question.

Comment: Getting  this http://paste.ofcode.org/JLwK4iCcjZEKPyRi3Yrvx3 Also attached in screenshot.please guide me.